# Apache FOP: List of errors after adding Apache FOP Maven dependency

Tags: java, xml, maven, apache-fop, java-14

Now I'm working on a JDK-14 application which calls to a SOAP Web Service, and after receiving a XML result next it must call a method to generate a PDF document via Apache FOP library. Please note that I'm not using **module-info.java** for this project.

This is my current list of dependencies in Maven. All the project was running without problems. But **after** adding the two Apache FOP dependencies (see below), it is not possible to compile and run the application anymore.

```
<dependencies>
        <!-- Dependencies for XML marshaling and more -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Runtime -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.3</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Dependencies for Web Service -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.xml.ws-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.jws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.jws-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>rt</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Dependencies for Apache PDF -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlgraphics-commons</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
            <artifactId>fop</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--Dependencies for QR Code-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.zxing</groupId>
            <artifactId>core</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.zxing</groupId>
            <artifactId>javase</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

The error messages varies from:

```
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
The package javax.xml.namespace is accessible from more than one module: <unnamed>, java.xmlJava(8390063)

import javax.xml.transform.Result;
The package javax.xml.transform is accessible from more than one module: <unnamed>, java.xmlJava(8390063)

import javax.xml.transform.sax.SAXResult;
The package javax.xml.transform.sax is accessible from more than one module: <unnamed>, java.xmlJava(8390063)

import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;
The package javax.xml.transform.stream is accessible from more than one module: <unnamed>, java.xmlJava(8390063)

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
The package javax.xml.parsers is accessible from more than one module: <unnamed>, java.xmlJava(8390063)
```

I want to know how can I deal with this problem. Maybe using an **exclusion** tag inside the specific dependency in conflict?

**PD. At the end it is possible to generate the PDF document, just by calling directly the Apache FOP jar from the command line.**

```
java -jar fop.jar -r -xml <xml_path> -xsl <xsl_path> -param name1 value1 -param name2 value2 ... myPDF.pdf
```

But I want to know (1) if is still possible to configure via code. And (2) why this is happening now. The project was running with JDK-11 and JDK-13 before migration to JDK-14.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not too certain quite why this problem occurs with recent JDK's.

With `JDK-8`, it's ok.

Of course, the `javax.xml` package is in the `xml-apis` dependency of `apache-fop` and in `JDK-14`, but that was also the case previously.

But anyway, the following `dependency-exclusion` solved the problem for me under `JDK-14` using `Eclipse-2020-06`:

```
<!DOCTYPE xml>
<project
        xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.stackoverflow</groupId>
    <artifactId>apache.fop.jdk14.exclude.xml-apis</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.target>14</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>14</maven.compiler.source>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
            <artifactId>fop</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <exclusions><exclusion><groupId>xml-apis</groupId><artifactId>*</artifactId></exclusion></exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: *"I'm not too certain quite why this problem occurs with recent JDK's."* Someone else elsewhere on another person having this problem said that starting with Java 9 (1.9?) you were not allowed to *..."have a package accessible from more than one module."*   He never explained what a package is, what a module is, what it means for a package to be accessible from a module, how you not make a package accessible from another module. But it was something that for some reason Java 9 (1.9?) intentionally broke without explanation.